# У меня выдает ошибку expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "float", а также subscript requires array or pointer type

Tags: c++

В массиве А[i,j]m,n представляет собой n - элементы больше некоторого значения R=3.5. Построить из массива А массив В, сделав перестановку так, чтобы все элементы более чем R попали в первую строку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
    int main() {
    int i, j = 0, p, n, m, o = 0;
        float A[30], B[30];
    while (true)
    {
        cout << " Input n and m ";
        cin >> n >> m;
        if (n > 0 && n <= 30) break;
        cout << " Error! n > 0 && n <= 30" << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cout << " Input A[" << i << "," << j << "]: ";
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    cout << " The array  A\n" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "A[" << i << "] = " << A[i] << "\n";
        cout << endl;
    }
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                B[i][j] = A[i][j];
        cin >> B[i][j];
    }
    p = 0;
    float r = 3.5;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)

                if (A[i][j] > 3.5)
                {
                    B[o][p] = r;
                    B[o][p] = B[i][j];
                    B[i][j] = r;
                    p++;
                }
}
```

Comment: `float B[30]; ... B[i][j]` <- замечаете некоторое противоречие между объявлением массива и применяемым к нему способом индексации? :)

Answer (score 0):

У вас сплошные ошибки.
Та, о которой вы написали - вы обращаетесь к к одномерному массиву, как к двумерному.

```
int main() 
{
   float A[30], B[30];
   ....
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
         B[i][j] = A[i][j];
   
   cin >> B[i][j];
```